# Can I say "perspective is all"

Tags: grammar

I want to write "perspective is everything" but due to characters limitations on Instagram that is not possible, so can I replace it with "Perspective is all"? and can I say "All is perspective" also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insta will accept both of those sentences, and both sentences are grammatical and make sense. In short, nothing is standing in your way.